# Compile time error for plist entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to generate a build error if a plist entry is not present. How can I approach it  ? Any information on this would helpful.

Comment: Check this [Show TODO's And FIXME's As Warnings In Xcode](https://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/show-todos-and-fixmes-as-warnings-in-xcode-4) for inspiration.

Comment: @rustylepord Check there is any element is present in .Plist document directory first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a script that checks the `.plist` file as part of the build.

See [Running a Script While Building a Product](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html).

If the script terminates with a non-zero exit code (i.e. `exit 1`) then the build will fail.

Answer (score 0):

MAC OS X's  has already a built in tool for your issue :- /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

```
For  success, it  returns exit code is 0
For failure, it  returns exit code is nonzero
For regular output is sent to stdout, error messages is sent to stderr
```